# issues with executing cablint-ct part of certlint tool

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to run the tool [certlint](https://github.com/awslabs/certlint), specifically the module called cablint-ct but when we try we get errors. There are three modules, certlint, cablint and cablint-ct -- all of which work except for cablint-ct.

Here is the command I am running in ruby:

```
ruby -I "/certlint-master/lib" "/certlint-master/bin/cablint-ct" "cert.der"
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
/certlint-master/lib/certlint/ct.rb:149:in `initialize': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /certlint-master/bin/cablint-ct:39:in `new'
from /certlint-master/bin/cablint-ct:39:in `<main>'
```

Here is the referring block of code in ct.rb (line 39):

```
30      def initialize(tbs_der)
31        asn = OpenSSL::ASN1.decode(tbs_der)
32        # tbsCertificate.version is optional, so we don't have a fixed
33        # offset. Check if the first item is a pure ASN1Data, which
34        # is a strong hint that it is an EXPLICIT wrapper for the first
35        # element in the struct.  If so, this is the version, so everything
36        # is offset by one.
37        skip = asn.value[0].instance_of?(OpenSSL::ASN1::ASN1Data) ? 1 : 0
38        sig_alg_der = asn.value[1 + skip].to_der
39        @raw = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence.new([tbs_der, sig_alg_der, DER_SIG]).to_der
40        super(@raw)
41      end
42    end
```

and ct.rb (line 149)

```
148    def initialize(log)
149      @log = URI.parse(log + '/').normalize
150    end
```

I've opened an [issue #37](https://github.com/awslabs/certlint/issues/37) on github with the owner of the tool but have not seen a response as of yet.

Will be grateful if someone can see if i am doing something wrong with my command or is there a coding issue somewhere?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I have figured that I need to be passing a URL into the command rather then a cert file. For example:

```
ruby -I "/certlint-master/lib" "/certlint-master/bin/cablint-ct" "https://ct.ws.symantec.com/ct/v1/get-entries?start=932966&end=932966"
```

I believe the code expect a JSON response from this URL and this link returns a file with JSON data, however, I get the following error:

```
/usr/share/ruby/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize': A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)
    from /usr/share/ruby/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
    from /usr/share/ruby/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from /certlint-master/lib/certlint/ct.rb:184:in `_call'
    from /certlint-master/lib/certlint/ct.rb:160:in `get_entries'
    from /certlint-master/bin/cablint-ct:40:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

resolved, the command expects a known ct log url and index id e.g.

`ruby -I "/certlint-master/lib" "/certlint-master/bin/cablint-ct" "https://ct.ws.symantec.com" 173977`

or

`ruby -I "/certlint-master/lib" "/certlint-master/bin/cablint-ct" "symantec" 173977`